# Printed result are null

Tags: java, null

This is excercise from my classes. I passed but I'm receiving null from last println's. Could you please help with examples? I want to understand code rather than make it work ;)

Thank you!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] namesWomen = new String[5];
        String[] namesMen = new String[5];
        String[] names = new String[5];
        Scanner reading = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the name: ");
            names[i] = reading.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Thank you!");

        }
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {
            var name = names[i];
            if (name.charAt(name.length() - 1) == 'a') {
                System.out.println("woman");
                namesWomen[namesWomen.length- 1] = name;
            } else {
                System.out.println("men");
                namesMen[namesMen.length- 1] = name;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesMen));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesWomen));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a new array as you did for `namesWomen` and `namesMen`, all of its elements are initialized to `null`. It looks like, in your code, there's only one place where you're changing a value within `namesWomen`:

```
namesWomen[namesWomen.length- 1] = name;
```

and one place where you're changing a value within `namesMen`:

```
namesMen[namesMen.length- 1] = name;
```

Both times, you're only changing the last element in the list, so all of the other elements remain `null` throughout the entire program.

Comment: And don't forget to close the `reading` Scanner by using `reading.close();` at the end of the method.

Comment: Ignore @Redi 's advice, it is exactly the wrong thing to do. Scanners of System.in should _not_ be closed.

Comment: Why shouldn't they?